# Split custom form into smaller functions for re usability

Tags: 8, forms

I've a created a custom form in custom module. I have couple fields in the form that can be reused to other form. Also as per the coding standards, the function should not be more than 150 lines. So I tried to split the form into multiple (2) functions. But that didn't work. (the second form didn't render into the first form)
Here is what I tried

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['some_element'] = [
       '#type' => 'textfield',
    ];
    ..
    ..
    if ($some_condition_exists) {
    //include second form here.
    $this->secondForm($param);
    }
    return $form;
    }

  public function secondForm($param) {
       $form['some_element'] = [
       '#type' => 'textfield',
       '#default_value' => $param
    ];
    return $form;
 }
```

Do I really need to put this form into another Form file and call `\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\module\Form\xxxForm');` ?

Comment: The only reason you want to add this complexity is from a coding standard guideline? Is there a functional reason for this need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just seem to be getting confused with the form build concept and PHP logic - what you need to do is add to the existing form array (`$form` in `buildForm`), not create a second separate form/array.

With that in mind, this:

```
$this->secondForm($param);
```

Doesn't do anything. You're not merging the return value back into `$form`, and you're not passing `$form` to `secondForm`, so that line and the lines in `secondForm` are basically a no-op.

There a bunch of different ways PHP will let you do what you need to, probably the simplest would be to pass the `$form`:

```
public function secondForm($param, array &$form) {
  $form['some_element'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => $param
  ];
}
```

And then

```
$this->secondForm($param, $form);
```

As an aside, it might be wise to rename `secondForm` to something like `addAdditionalElements`, just to avoid future confusion.

Comment: I usually have to build multistep ajax forms with lots of lines and I find splitting up a lot of related code into their own functions and passing $form by reference as answered here really helps me handle it all and I find it easier to go back to and read.

Answer (score 0):

Without any details about what "it's not working" means, and if this is your real code, you call `$this->secondForm()` which returns something, but you don't set it to a variable.

If you update that line to something like `$form = $this->secondForm();`, this should technically work.

Comment: That will replace any of the current values in `$form` ... `$form += $this->secondForm();` would do it though

Comment: The code shown from the OP doesn't use what `secondForm()` is returning. That's what doesn't work.